# Using formula and counter in an array

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.8.7

What I have is:

```
array.map!{
    |c| c*(y**(z-1))
    z=z+1
}
```

`array` contains

```
[10, 10, 10]
```

The output isn't what I want, it is

```
[2, 3, 4]
```

I want the z to function as a counter, it was defined earlier as 1, and the y was defined earlier. also, as 16 or 36 (depending on user input)

So if I input the same array with 3 10s. I want `array` to be (when the y is 16):

```
[10, 160, 2560]
```

Answer (score 3):

There are more idiomatic ways to achieve this in ruby, for instance:

```
y = 16
array = Array.new(3) { |i| 10*(y**i) }
# => [10, 160, 2560]
```

Or alternatively, if the contents are not always the constant `10`, there is this:

```
y = 16
array = [10, 10, 10]
array.map!.with_index { |c, i| c*(y**i) }
# => [10, 160, 2560]
```

The above two examples leave the indexing to the looping construct, which is good, because it's one less thing for you to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

Write it as

```
z = 1; y =16
array = [10, 10, 10]
array.map { |c| z=z+1 ; c*(y**(z-2))  }
# => [10, 160, 2560]
```

With [`Array#map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-map-21), block returned the last expression for each iteration. In your case it was `z = z + 1`. Your initial `z` was `1`. So in your first `z = z+1` evaluated and it was `2`, next iteration it incremented again by `1`, so value of `z` is `3`, same way in the last pass `z` becomes `4`. So finally you got the new array as `[2, 3, 4]`.

One Rubyish way :

```
y = 16
3.times.map{|i| 10*y**i}  # => [10, 160, 2560]
```